# What does "action" refer to in this quote?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "action" refer to in the context below?

> The established film industries in certain countries have huge budgets for **action**, special effects and to shoot scenes in spectacular locations.
>
> <sup>(quote taken from [Sample 3](http://www.ielts-mentor.com/writing-sample/writing-task-2/2028-ielts-writing-task-2-sample-894-many-people-prefer-to-watch-foreign-films-than-locally-produced-films) in an IELTS Writing Task)</sup>

I can't decide what is exactly referred to by **action** that needs huge budgets to be done in the filming industry. Would you help me to clarify?

Answer (score 8):

'Dialog' scenes typically involve only a few actors and cameras, and are typically shot as sequences of medium shots and closeups in with little or no motion by either the actors or the cameras. They often take place in fairly confined spaces and can be shot on a sound stage; and even when they take place out of doors they don't require elaborate planning and dressing.

'Action' scenes, however—traveling shots, combats and battles, car chases, and the like—employ many actors and cameras, and usually have to be shot 'on location', in spaces which are not designed to make shooting efficient. It takes many hours of planning and shooting and enormous quantities of equipment and staff to capture even a few seconds of usable footage.